# SQL Alchemy filter field based on truthy value

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

In MySQL, it's very easy to filter rows based on truthy values on a column. For instance, given a table `reviews`:

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The this query will display ids for all reviews with a truthy rating score (all except 0, '' and NULL).

```
SELECT id FROM review WHERE rating;
```

So my question is, how can we port that logic in a SQL Alchemy API without enlisting all the different falsey cases?

Comment: You should be able to do the exact same thing (`.filter(Review.rating)`). Does that not work?

Comment: @univerio that did work! Thanks. I don't recall why it wasn't working for me last time - hmm weird.